# Flutter - Wrap doesn't center RichText

Tags: android, flutter, mobile

```
Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Center(
            child: SizedBox(
              width: screenWidth * 0.8,
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Container(
                    color: Colors.yellow,
                    padding: const EdgeInsetsDirectional.only(start: 16.0),
                    child: SizedBox(
                      width: double.infinity,
                      child: Wrap(
                        runAlignment: WrapAlignment.center,
                        crossAxisAlignment: WrapCrossAlignment.center,
                        alignment: WrapAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          RichText(
                            text: TextSpan(
                              text: 'afda fd afd asf das fds',
                              children: [
                                TextSpan(
                                  text: 'fda fda fd asfd sa',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                                    decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                                  ),
                                  recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()
                                    ..onTap = () {
                                      // Handle the click action for terms and conditions link
                                      print("tap");
                                    },
                                ),
                                const TextSpan(
                                  text: ' fdsa ',
                                ),
                                TextSpan(
                                  text: 'fdsafdafda sf dsa',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                                    decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                                  ),
                                  recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()
                                    ..onTap = () async {
                                      await launchUrl(
                                          Uri.parse('https://flutter.dev'));
                                    },
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    )
```

This is the result:
[image]

I want the second line of text to be centered. If I put a few containers as children of Wrap, it does center them, but it doesn't work for the RichText or Text.rich(...).
The app is rtl so the text is on the right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To center the text, you need to use `textAlign: TextAlign.center`

```dart
RichText(
  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
  text: TextSpan(
```

[image]

Comment: That's what I was looking for, don't know why it didn't appear...

Comment: Glad to help,for more you can check [RichText](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RichText-class.html) and how [/layout/constraints works](https://docs.flutter.dev/ui/layout/constraints)